# Тире или двоеточие в случае с перечислением?

Tags: пунктуация

Сомневаюсь, что ставить после "точки 2 и 3" ― тире или двоеточие.
*Для этой точки решение четырех уравнений системы имеет следующие значения: х, у, z..., для точки 2 (?) x1, y1,z1, для точки 3 (?)...*

Comment: Вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он по проблеме редактирования технического текста.

Answer (score 3):

После 2 и 3 лучше, по-моему, поставить **тире**. После 2 и 3 **пропущена фраза**  ***решение четырех уравнений системы имеет следующие значения***, а на месте пропущенных слов положено ставить **тире**.

Для этой точки решение четырех уравнений системы имеет следующие значения: х, у, z..., для точки 2 ― x1, y1,z1, для точки 3 ―  ...

Comment: Спасибо! Помогли

Answer (score 0):

Точку с запятой здесь обычно ставят. Тогда тире выглядит вполне разумно и наглядно, оно заменяет пропущенную группу слов:

***Для этой точки решение четырех уравнений системы имеет следующие значения: х, у, z...; для точки 2 - x1, y1, z1...; для точки 3 - ...***

Я правильно понимаю, что многоточия здесь показывает, что ряд x, у, z ... на третьем члене не обрывается?

Но это прием, пригодный только для математизированного текста, по обычным правилам какой-либо знак после многоточия невозможен в принципе.

Comment: Спасибо! Точка 3 последняя

Answer (score 0):

"решение уравнений системы ... имеет следующие значения" - звучит коряво.  Не "решение уравнений системы", а "решение системы уравнений"; не "имеет значения", а "представляет собой набор значений". Почему после z стоит многоточие  - непонятно. Если это система четырех уравнений с четырьмя неизвестными и одно из значений определено (так я понимаю смысл слов "для этой точки"), то решением должен быть набор из трех значений. Предлагаю как вариант: **Для этой точки решением системы четырех уравнений является следующий набор значений: x, y, z, для точки 2 - x1, y1, z1, для точки 3 - x2, y2, z2.**